# Polymorphism with pointers/boost::shared_ptr

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, polymorphism

Consider the following example of polymorphism in C++. To me, this is unexpected behavior, which probably lies in the fact that I am still thinking too much in Java. The question to me is now: How do I get the pointer example to call the more specific method.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <boost/tr1/memory.hpp>

class Image {
 public:
  Image(std::string className = "Image") 
      : className_(className)
    {}

  virtual ~Image() {}

  virtual std::string className() {
    return className_;
  }

 private:
  std::string className_;
};

class RightImage : public Image {
 public:
  RightImage()
      : Image("RightImage")
    {}
};

class Processor{
 public:
  void process(Image& image){
    std::cout << "Invoking process(Image& image) with image of type \"" << image.className() << "\"" << std::endl;
  }
  void process(RightImage& rightImage){
    std::cout << "Invoking process(RightImage& rightImage) with rightImage of type \"" << rightImage.className()  << "\"" << std::endl;
  }

  void process(Image* image){
    std::cout << "Invoking process(Image* image) with image of type \"" << image->className() << "\"" << std::endl;
  }
  void process(RightImage* rightImage){
    std::cout << "Invoking process(RightImage* rightImage) with rightImage of type \"" << rightImage->className()  << "\"" << std::endl;
  }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
      std::tr1::shared_ptr<Image> rightImageSharedPtr(new RightImage());
      Image* rightImagePointer = new RightImage();
      RightImage rightImage;
      Processor processor;
      std::cout << "value:                   ";
      processor.process(rightImage);
      std::cout << "shared_ptr:              ";
      processor.process(*rightImageSharedPtr);
      std::cout << "old fashioned pointer 1: ";
      processor.process(*rightImagePointer);
      std::cout << "old fashioned pointer 2: ";
      processor.process(rightImagePointer);
}
```

The output of that program is:

> value:                   Invoking process(RightImage& rightImage) with rightImage of type "RightImage"
>
> shared_ptr:              Invoking process(Image& image) with image of type "RightImage"
>
> old fashioned pointer 1: Invoking process(Image& image) with image of type "RightImage"
>
> old fashioned pointer 2: Invoking process(Image* image) with image of type "RightImage"

How can I make the last three examples also call `process(RightImage&)` and `process(RightImage*)`?

Comment: And this is supposed to work in Java?

Comment: @curiousguy No, it's not. But in Java I could use reflection to get the class type ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next to the [double dispatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch) as proposed by tokage, you could also have only 1 Process() function with the base class reference as parameter and then use polymorphism by calling virtual function of the base class inside the Process() function.

Comment: The way I described it in the example would probably mandate a visitor pattern, however in my concrete problem I got away with having a virtual `process()` function in the `Image` class and using polymorphism.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like double dispatch/ Visitor Pattern to solve your problem.

The information which type your Image really is under the interface is only available inside the object. So you need to call a virtual method on the image object to get at your underlying type.

Example:

```
class Image{
    virtual void process(Processor &processor)=0;
}

class RightImage{
    virtual void process(Processor &processor){
        processor.process(this);
    }
}
```

Of course you also could do the processing inside the image class in the process()-Method, but I suspect you want different kinds of processors to work on different types of images.
Another option - which is a bit cleaner maybe - is to have the processor call virtual methods for the single processing steps where they differ for the image types.

Comment: Ok, I should have had the visitor pattern idea myself :-)

Answer (score 0):

Overloading is resolved on the static types of a function's arguments so you need to declare your variables as

```
  std::tr1::shared_ptr<RightImage> rightImageSharedPtr(new RightImage());
  RightImage* rightImagePointer = new RightImage();
```

The alternative is to perform a dynamic_cast before calling each function, which is just a more convoluted way of doing the same thing.

Comment: Ideally `Image` would be my interface and I would pass in a Subtype of it for processing, so this is not exactly applicable to my design.

Comment: @sebastiangeiger: You simply shouldn't *have* a separate overload for the subtype if that's your design. Everything should be done through the common interface.